# java graphic bugs when called from another class

Tags: java, graphics, components

I am writing a program, on which I just simply write, edit and show some short entries. So far, everything is working just fine and I was pretty much done, but for some reason now the Gui starts messing with me. Meaning, at the beginning everything is normal, but when I am e.g. trying to switch back from the second Gui to the first, it will still show the button, graphics etc. of the second Gui. Strangly, when I am making the changes directly at the main file and not at the other class, it works just fine - even though I think icalled everything correctly, I just bothers me and I cannot figure out the reason. Thank you very much for any help I can get!

Here are some code snippets:

JFrame:

```
package main;

public class JFD3 extends JFrame {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private JPanel contentPane;
int Gui=1;
public JTextField txtFilter;
public JButton btnNewEntry;
public JScrollPane spDefault;
public JTextArea txtDefault;
public JScrollPane spEntry;
public JButton btnBack;
public JButton btnEdit;
public JTextArea txtEntry;
public static boolean entry=true;
public static File cEntry;
public JButton btnSave;
public JTextField txtTitle;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                JFD3 frame = new JFD3();
                frame.setVisible(true);
                frame.setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("C:/Users/Admin/workspace/JFD3/files/icon/icon.jpeg"));
                frame.setTitle("JavaFunctionsDatabase3");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

public JFD3() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    spDefault = new JScrollPane();
    spDefault.setBounds(12, 66, 225, 174);
    contentPane.add(spDefault);
    txtDefault = new JTextArea();
    txtDefault.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
            int line=0;
            try {
                 line = txtDefault.getLineOfOffset(txtDefault.getCaretPosition());
            } catch (BadLocationException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            ShowEntry showentry = new ShowEntry();
            try {
                showentry.ProveLine(line, txtFilter);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if(entry==true){
                Gui=2;
                repaint();
            }
        }
    });
    txtDefault.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    spDefault.setViewportView(txtDefault);
    txtDefault.setEditable(false);

    txtFilter = new JTextField();
    txtFilter.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {
            repaint();
        }
    });
    txtFilter.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 18));
    txtFilter.setBounds(249, 153, 168, 41);
    contentPane.add(txtFilter);
    txtFilter.setColumns(10);

    btnNewEntry = new JButton("New Entry");
    btnNewEntry.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            Gui=4;
            repaint();
        }
    });
    btnNewEntry.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 18));
    btnNewEntry.setBounds(249, 66, 168, 41);
    contentPane.add(btnNewEntry);
    btnNewEntry.setFocusable(false);
    btnNewEntry.setBackground(Color.GRAY);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel(){
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        public void paint(Graphics g){
            try {
                CreateGui(g);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    panel.setBounds(0, 0, 432, 262);
    contentPane.add(panel);

    spEntry = new JScrollPane();
    spEntry.setBounds(12, 66, 225, 174);
    contentPane.add(spEntry);
    txtEntry = new JTextArea();
    txtEntry.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 16));
    txtEntry.setEditable(false);
    spEntry.setViewportView(txtEntry);
    spEntry.setVisible(false);

    btnEdit = new JButton("Edit Entry");
    btnEdit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Gui=3;
            repaint();
        }
    });
    btnEdit.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 18));
    btnEdit.setBounds(249, 66, 168, 41);
    contentPane.add(btnEdit);
    btnEdit.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    btnEdit.setVisible(false);
    btnEdit.setFocusable(false);

    btnBack = new JButton("Back");
    btnBack.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            if(Gui==2||Gui==4){
                Gui=1;
                txtEntry.setText("");
                txtTitle.setText("");
                repaint();
            }else{
                Gui=2;
                repaint();
            }
        }
    });
    btnBack.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 18));
    btnBack.setBounds(249, 116, 168, 41);
    contentPane.add(btnBack);
    btnBack.setVisible(false);
    btnBack.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    btnBack.setFocusable(false);

    btnSave = new JButton("Save Entry");
    btnSave.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            if(Gui==3){
                try {
                    EditEntry editentry = new EditEntry();
                    editentry.SaveEntry(txtEntry, txtTitle);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Gui=2;
                repaint();
            }else{
                if(!txtEntry.getText().equals("")&&!txtTitle.getText().equals("")){
                    try {
                        NewEntry newentry = new NewEntry();
                        newentry.SaveEntry(txtTitle, txtEntry);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    txtEntry.setText("");
                    txtTitle.setText("");
                    Gui=1;
                    repaint();
                }
            }
        }
    });
    btnSave.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 18));
    btnSave.setBounds(249, 66, 168, 41);
    contentPane.add(btnSave);
    btnSave.setFocusable(false);
    btnSave.setVisible(false);
    btnSave.setBackground(Color.GRAY);

    txtTitle = new JTextField();
    txtTitle.setBounds(12, 15, 225, 35);
    txtTitle.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 32));
    contentPane.add(txtTitle);
    txtTitle.setColumns(10);
    txtTitle.setVisible(false);
}

public void CreateGui(Graphics g) throws IOException{
    if(Gui==1){
        Default default1 = new Default();
        default1.CreateGui(g, spDefault, txtFilter, btnNewEntry, txtDefault, spEntry, btnEdit, btnBack, txtTitle, txtEntry);
    }
    if(Gui==2){
        ShowEntry showentry = new ShowEntry();
        showentry.CreateGui(g, spDefault, txtFilter, btnNewEntry, txtDefault, spEntry, btnEdit, btnBack, txtEntry, txtTitle);
        showentry.FillEntry(txtEntry);
    }
    if(Gui==3){
        EditEntry editentry = new EditEntry();
        editentry.CreateGui(txtEntry, btnEdit, btnSave, txtTitle);
    }
    if(Gui==4){
        NewEntry newentry = new NewEntry();
        newentry.CreateGui(btnSave, btnBack, txtTitle, txtEntry, spDefault, spEntry, btnNewEntry, txtFilter);
    }
}
}
```

the default class which should change the gui

```
  package main;

public class Default extends JFD3{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
File[] L = F.listFiles();
boolean filter=true;

public void CreateGui(Graphics g, JScrollPane spDefault, JTextField txtFilter, JButton btnNewEntry, JTextArea txtDefault, JScrollPane spEntry, JButton btnEdit, JButton btnBack, JTextField txtTitle, JTextArea txtEntry) throws IOException{
    spDefault.setVisible(true);
    txtFilter.setVisible(true);
    btnNewEntry.setVisible(true);
    spEntry.setVisible(false);
    btnBack.setVisible(false);
    btnEdit.setVisible(false);
    txtEntry.setEditable(false);
    txtTitle.setVisible(false);
    g.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 32));
    g.drawString("JavaFunctionsDatabase3", 15, 45);
    g.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    g.drawString("Filter", 249, 145);
    ShowEntries(txtDefault, txtFilter);
}
```

Comment: Never create components in a paint() method. You will likely end up recursively creating thousands of new items,

Answer (score 1):

@FredK,
thank you very much for your quick response, I did not know that. Now I changed my code accordingly, but unfortunaly I get a StackOverFlowError now, that I have not had before. I would be very pleased by a solution for this as well, thank you!

Here is the changed code:

```
public class JFD3 extends JFrame {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private JPanel contentPane;
int Gui=1;
public JTextField txtFilter;
public JButton btnNewEntry;
public JScrollPane spDefault;
public JTextArea txtDefault;
public JScrollPane spEntry;
public JButton btnBack;
public JButton btnEdit;
public JTextArea txtEntry;
public static boolean entry=true;
public static File cEntry;
public JButton btnSave;
public JTextField txtTitle;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                JFD3 frame = new JFD3();
                frame.setVisible(true);
                frame.setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("C:/Users/wittn/workspace/JFD3/files/icon/icon.jpeg"));
                frame.setTitle("JavaFunctionsDatabase3");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

public JFD3() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    spDefault = new JScrollPane();
    spDefault.setBounds(12, 66, 225, 174);
    contentPane.add(spDefault);
    txtDefault = new JTextArea();
    txtDefault.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
            int line=0;
            try {
                 line = txtDefault.getLineOfOffset(txtDefault.getCaretPosition());
            } catch (BadLocationException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            ShowEntry showentry = new ShowEntry();
            try {
                showentry.ProveLine(line, txtFilter);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if(entry==true){
                Gui=2;
                repaint();
                try {
                    CreateGui();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });
    txtDefault.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    spDefault.setViewportView(txtDefault);
    txtDefault.setEditable(false);

    txtFilter = new JTextField();
    txtFilter.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {
            repaint();
            try {
                CreateGui();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    txtFilter.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 18));
    txtFilter.setBounds(249, 153, 168, 41);
    contentPane.add(txtFilter);
    txtFilter.setColumns(10);

    btnNewEntry = new JButton("New Entry");
    btnNewEntry.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            Gui=4;
            repaint();
            try {
                CreateGui();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    btnNewEntry.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 18));
    btnNewEntry.setBounds(249, 66, 168, 41);
    contentPane.add(btnNewEntry);
    btnNewEntry.setFocusable(false);
    btnNewEntry.setBackground(Color.GRAY);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel(){
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        public void paint(Graphics g){
            GraphicGui(g);
            try {
                CreateGui();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    panel.setBounds(0, 0, 432, 262);
    contentPane.add(panel);

    spEntry = new JScrollPane();
    spEntry.setBounds(12, 66, 225, 174);
    contentPane.add(spEntry);
    txtEntry = new JTextArea();
    txtEntry.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 16));
    txtEntry.setEditable(false);
    spEntry.setViewportView(txtEntry);
    spEntry.setVisible(false);

    btnEdit = new JButton("Edit Entry");
    btnEdit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Gui=3;
            repaint();
            try {
                CreateGui();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    btnEdit.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 18));
    btnEdit.setBounds(249, 66, 168, 41);
    contentPane.add(btnEdit);
    btnEdit.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    btnEdit.setVisible(false);
    btnEdit.setFocusable(false);

    btnBack = new JButton("Back");
    btnBack.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            if(Gui==2||Gui==4){
                Gui=1;
                txtEntry.setText("");
                txtTitle.setText("");
            }else{
                Gui=2;
            }
            repaint();
            try {
                CreateGui();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    btnBack.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 18));
    btnBack.setBounds(249, 116, 168, 41);
    contentPane.add(btnBack);
    btnBack.setVisible(false);
    btnBack.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    btnBack.setFocusable(false);

    btnSave = new JButton("Save Entry");
    btnSave.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            if(Gui==3){
                try {
                    EditEntry editentry = new EditEntry();
                    editentry.SaveEntry(txtEntry, txtTitle);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Gui=2;
                repaint();
            }else{
                if(!txtEntry.getText().equals("")&&!txtTitle.getText().equals("")){
                    try {
                        NewEntry newentry = new NewEntry();
                        newentry.SaveEntry(txtTitle, txtEntry);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    txtEntry.setText("");
                    txtTitle.setText("");
                    Gui=1;
                    repaint();
                    try {
                        CreateGui();
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
    btnSave.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 18));
    btnSave.setBounds(249, 66, 168, 41);
    contentPane.add(btnSave);
    btnSave.setFocusable(false);
    btnSave.setVisible(false);
    btnSave.setBackground(Color.GRAY);

    txtTitle = new JTextField();
    txtTitle.setBounds(12, 15, 225, 35);
    txtTitle.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 32));
    contentPane.add(txtTitle);
    txtTitle.setColumns(10);
    txtTitle.setVisible(false);

    repaint();
    try {
        CreateGui();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void CreateGui() throws IOException{
    if(Gui==1){
        Default default1 = new Default();
        default1.CreateGui(spDefault, txtFilter, btnNewEntry, txtDefault, spEntry, btnEdit, btnBack, txtTitle, txtEntry);
    }
    if(Gui==2){
        ShowEntry showentry = new ShowEntry();
        showentry.CreateGui(spDefault, txtFilter, btnNewEntry, txtDefault, spEntry, btnEdit, btnBack, txtEntry, txtTitle);
        showentry.FillEntry(txtEntry);
    }
    if(Gui==3){
        EditEntry editentry = new EditEntry();
        editentry.CreateGui(txtEntry, btnEdit, btnSave, txtTitle);
    }
    if(Gui==4){
        NewEntry newentry = new NewEntry();
        newentry.CreateGui(btnSave, btnBack, txtTitle, txtEntry, spDefault, spEntry, btnNewEntry, txtFilter);
    }
}

public void GraphicGui(Graphics g){
    if(Gui==1){
        Default default1 = new Default();
        default1.CreateGraphicGui(g);
    }
    if(Gui==2){
        ShowEntry showentry = new ShowEntry();
        showentry.CreateGraphicGui(g);
    }
}
}
```

the other class again

```
public void CreateGui(JScrollPane spDefault, JTextField txtFilter, JButton btnNewEntry, JTextArea txtDefault, JScrollPane spEntry, JButton btnEdit, JButton btnBack, JTextField txtTitle, JTextArea txtEntry) throws IOException{
    spDefault.setVisible(true);
    txtFilter.setVisible(true);
    btnNewEntry.setVisible(true);
    spEntry.setVisible(false);
    btnBack.setVisible(false);
    btnEdit.setVisible(false);
    txtEntry.setEditable(false);
    txtTitle.setVisible(false);
    ShowEntries(txtDefault, txtFilter);
}

public void CreateGraphicGui(Graphics g){
    g.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 32));
    g.drawString("JavaFunctionsDatabase3", 15, 45);
    g.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    g.drawString("Filter", 249, 145);
}
```

the error:

```
 Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at sun.util.locale.InternalLocaleBuilder.setExtensions(Unknown Source)
at sun.util.locale.InternalLocaleBuilder.setLanguageTag(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Locale.forLanguageTag(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.windows.WInputMethodDescriptor.getNativeAvailableLocales(Native Method)
at sun.awt.windows.WInputMethodDescriptor.getAvailableLocalesInternal(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.windows.WInputMethodDescriptor.getAvailableLocales(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.im.InputMethodLocator.isLocaleAvailable(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.im.ExecutableInputMethodManager.findInputMethod(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.im.InputContext.selectInputMethod(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.im.InputContext.<init>(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.im.InputMethodContext.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.im.InputContext.getInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.getInputContext(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.getInputContext(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.getInputContext(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.getInputContext(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.getInputContext(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.getInputContext(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.getInputContext(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.enableInputMethods(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.text.JTextComponent.setEditable(Unknown Source)
at main.JFD3.<init>(JFD3.java:100)
at main.Default.<init>(Default.java:14)
at main.JFD3.CreateGui(JFD3.java:260)
at main.JFD3.<init>(JFD3.java:252)
at main.Default.<init>(Default.java:14)
at main.JFD3.CreateGui(JFD3.java:260)
at main.JFD3.<init>(JFD3.java:252)
at main.Default.<init>(Default.java:14)
at main.JFD3.CreateGui(JFD3.java:260)
at main.JFD3.<init>(JFD3.java:252)
at main.Default.<init>(Default.java:14)
at main.JFD3.CreateGui(JFD3.java:260)
at main.JFD3.<init>(JFD3.java:252)
at main.Default.<init>(Default.java:14)
at main.JFD3.CreateGui(JFD3.java:260)
at main.JFD3.<init>(JFD3.java:252)
at main.Default.<init>(Default.java:14)
at main.JFD3.CreateGui(JFD3.java:260)
at main.JFD3.<init>(JFD3.java:252)
at main.Default.<init>(Default.java:14)
at main.JFD3.CreateGui(JFD3.java:260)
at main.JFD3.<init>(JFD3.java:252)
at main.Default.<init>(Default.java:14)
at main.JFD3.CreateGui(JFD3.java:260)
at main.JFD3.<init>(JFD3.java:252)
at main.Default.<init>(Default.java:14)
at main.JFD3.CreateGui(JFD3.java:260)
at main.JFD3.<init>(JFD3.java:252)
at main.Default.<init>(Default.java:14)
at main.JFD3.CreateGui(JFD3.java:260)
at main.JFD3.<init>(JFD3.java:252)
at main.Default.<init>(Default.java:14)
at main.JFD3.CreateGui(JFD3.java:260)
at main.JFD3.<init>(JFD3.java:252)
at main.Default.<init>(Default.java:14)
at main.JFD3.CreateGui(JFD3.java:260)
at main.JFD3.<init>(JFD3.java:252)
at main.Default.<init>(Default.java:14)
at main.JFD3.CreateGui(JFD3.java:260)
at main.JFD3.<init>(JFD3.java:252)
at main.Default.<init>(Default.java:14)
at main.JFD3.CreateGui(JFD3.java:260)
at main.JFD3.<init>(JFD3.java:252)
at main.Default.<init>(Default.java:14)
at main.JFD3.CreateGui(JFD3.java:260)
at main.JFD3.<init>(JFD3.java:252)
at main.Default.<init>(Default.java:14)
at main.JFD3.CreateGui(JFD3.java:260)
at main.JFD3.<init>(JFD3.java:252)
at main.Default.<init>(Default.java:14)
at main.JFD3.CreateGui(JFD3.java:260)
at main.JFD3.<init>(JFD3.java:252)
at main.Default.<init>(Default.java:14)
at main.JFD3.CreateGui(JFD3.java:260)
at main.JFD3.<init>(JFD3.java:252)
at main.Default.<init>(Default.java:14)
at main.JFD3.CreateGui(JFD3.java:260)
at main.JFD3.<init>(JFD3.java:252)
at main.Default.<init>(Default.java:14)
at main.JFD3.CreateGui(JFD3.java:260)
at main.JFD3.<init>(JFD3.java:252)
at main.Default.<init>(Default.java:14)
at main.JFD3.CreateGui(JFD3.java:260)
at main.JFD3.<init>(JFD3.java:252)
at main.Default.<init>(Default.java:14)
at main.JFD3.CreateGui(JFD3.java:260)
at main.JFD3.<init>(JFD3.java:252)
at main.Default.<init>(Default.java:14)
at main.JFD3.CreateGui(JFD3.java:260)
at main.JFD3.<init>(JFD3.java:252)
at main.Default.<init>(Default.java:14)
at main.JFD3.CreateGui(JFD3.java:260)
at main.JFD3.<init>(JFD3.java:252)
at main.Default.<init>(Default.java:14)
at main.JFD3.CreateGui(JFD3.java:260)
at main.JFD3.<init>(JFD3.java:252)
at main.Default.<init>(Default.java:14)
at main.JFD3.CreateGui(JFD3.java:260)
at main.JFD3.<init>(JFD3.java:252)
at main.Default.<init>(Default.java:14)
at main.JFD3.CreateGui(JFD3.java:260)
at main.JFD3.<init>(JFD3.java:252)
at main.Default.<init>(Default.java:14)
at main.JFD3.CreateGui(JFD3.java:260)
at main.JFD3.<init>(JFD3.java:252)
at main.Default.<init>(Default.java:14)
at main.JFD3.CreateGui(JFD3.java:260)
at main.JFD3.<init>(JFD3.java:252)
at main.Default.<init>(Default.java:14)
at main.JFD3.CreateGui(JFD3.java:260)
at main.JFD3.<init>(JFD3.java:252)
at main.Default.<init>(Default.java:14)
at main.JFD3.CreateGui(JFD3.java:260)
at main.JFD3.<init>(JFD3.java:252)
at main.Default.<init>(Default.java:14)
at main.JFD3.CreateGui(JFD3.java:260)
at main.JFD3.<init>(JFD3.java:252)
at main.Default.<init>(Default.java:14)
at main.JFD3.CreateGui(JFD3.java:260)
at main.JFD3.<init>(JFD3.java:252)
at main.Default.<init>(Default.java:14)
at main.JFD3.CreateGui(JFD3.java:260)
at main.JFD3.<init>(JFD3.java:252)
at main.Default.<init>(Default.java:14)
at main.JFD3.CreateGui(JFD3.java:260)
at main.JFD3.<init>(JFD3.java:252)
at main.Default.<init>(Default.java:14)
at main.JFD3.CreateGui(JFD3.java:260)
at main.JFD3.<init>(JFD3.java:252)
at main.Default.<init>(Default.java:14)
at main.JFD3.CreateGui(JFD3.java:260)
at main.JFD3.<init>(JFD3.java:252)
at main.Default.<init>(Default.java:14)
at main.JFD3.CreateGui(JFD3.java:260)
at main.JFD3.<init>(JFD3.java:252)
at main.Default.<init>(Default.java:14)
at main.JFD3.CreateGui(JFD3.java:260)
at main.JFD3.<init>(JFD3.java:252)
at main.Default.<init>(Default.java:14)
at main.JFD3.CreateGui(JFD3.java:260)
at main.JFD3.<init>(JFD3.java:252)
at main.Default.<init>(Default.java:14)
at main.JFD3.CreateGui(JFD3.java:260)
at main.JFD3.<init>(JFD3.java:252)
at main.Default.<init>(Default.java:14)
at main.JFD3.CreateGui(JFD3.java:260)
at main.JFD3.<init>(JFD3.java:252)
at main.Default.<init>(Default.java:14)
at main.JFD3.CreateGui(JFD3.java:260)
at main.JFD3.<init>(JFD3.java:252)
at main.Default.<init>(Default.java:14)
at main.JFD3.CreateGui(JFD3.java:260)
at main.JFD3.<init>(JFD3.java:252)
at main.Default.<init>(Default.java:14)
at main.JFD3.CreateGui(JFD3.java:260)
at main.JFD3.<init>(JFD3.java:252)
at main.Default.<init>(Default.java:14)
at main.JFD3.CreateGui(JFD3.java:260)
at main.JFD3.<init>(JFD3.java:252)
at main.Default.<init>(Default.java:14)
at main.JFD3.CreateGui(JFD3.java:260)
at main.JFD3.<init>(JFD3.java:252)
at main.Default.<init>(Default.java:14)
at main.JFD3.CreateGui(JFD3.java:260)
at main.JFD3.<init>(JFD3.java:252)
at main.Default.<init>(Default.java:14)
at main.JFD3.CreateGui(JFD3.java:260)
at main.JFD3.<init>(JFD3.java:252)
at main.Default.<init>(Default.java:14)
at main.JFD3.CreateGui(JFD3.java:260)
at main.JFD3.<init>(JFD3.java:252)
at main.Default.<init>(Default.java:14)
at main.JFD3.CreateGui(JFD3.java:260)
at main.JFD3.<init>(JFD3.java:252)
at main.Default.<init>(Default.java:14)
at main.JFD3.CreateGui(JFD3.java:260)
at main.JFD3.<init>(JFD3.java:252)
at main.Default.<init>(Default.java:14)
at main.JFD3.CreateGui(JFD3.java:260)
at main.JFD3.<init>(JFD3.java:252)
at main.Default.<init>(Default.java:14)
at main.JFD3.CreateGui(JFD3.java:260)
at main.JFD3.<init>(JFD3.java:252)
at main.Default.<init>(Default.java:14)
at main.JFD3.CreateGui(JFD3.java:260)
at main.JFD3.<init>(JFD3.java:252)
at main.Default.<init>(Default.java:14)
at main.JFD3.CreateGui(JFD3.java:260)
at main.JFD3.<init>(JFD3.java:252)
at main.Default.<init>(Default.java:14)
at main.JFD3.CreateGui(JFD3.java:260)
at main.JFD3.<init>(JFD3.java:252)
at main.Default.<init>(Default.java:14)
at main.JFD3.CreateGui(JFD3.java:260)
at main.JFD3.<init>(JFD3.java:252)
at main.Default.<init>(Default.java:14)
at main.JFD3.CreateGui(JFD3.java:260)
at main.JFD3.<init>(JFD3.java:252)
at main.Default.<init>(Default.java:14)
at main.JFD3.CreateGui(JFD3.java:260)
at main.JFD3.<init>(JFD3.java:252)
at main.Default.<init>(Default.java:14)
at main.JFD3.CreateGui(JFD3.java:260)
at main.JFD3.<init>(JFD3.java:252)
at main.Default.<init>(Default.java:14)
at main.JFD3.CreateGui(JFD3.java:260)
at main.JFD3.<init>(JFD3.java:252)
at main.Default.<init>(Default.java:14)
at main.JFD3.CreateGui(JFD3.java:260)
at main.JFD3.<init>(JFD3.java:252)
at main.Default.<init>(Default.java:14)
at main.JFD3.CreateGui(JFD3.java:260)
at main.JFD3.<init>(JFD3.java:252)
at main.Default.<init>(Default.java:14)
at main.JFD3.CreateGui(JFD3.java:260)
at main.JFD3.<init>(JFD3.java:252)
at main.Default.<init>(Default.java:14)
at main.JFD3.CreateGui(JFD3.java:260)
at main.JFD3.<init>(JFD3.java:252)
at main.Default.<init>(Default.java:14)
at main.JFD3.CreateGui(JFD3.java:260)
at main.JFD3.<init>(JFD3.java:252)
at main.Default.<init>(Default.java:14)
at main.JFD3.CreateGui(JFD3.java:260)
at main.JFD3.<init>(JFD3.java:252)
at main.Default.<init>(Default.java:14)
at main.JFD3.CreateGui(JFD3.java:260)
at main.JFD3.<init>(JFD3.java:252)
at main.Default.<init>(Default.java:14)
at main.JFD3.CreateGui(JFD3.java:260)
at main.JFD3.<init>(JFD3.java:252)
at main.Default.<init>(Default.java:14)
at main.JFD3.CreateGui(JFD3.java:260)
at main.JFD3.<init>(JFD3.java:252)
at main.Default.<init>(Default.java:14)
at main.JFD3.CreateGui(JFD3.java:260)
at main.JFD3.<init>(JFD3.java:252)
at main.Default.<init>(Default.java:14)
at main.JFD3.CreateGui(JFD3.java:260)
at main.JFD3.<init>(JFD3.java:252)
at main.Default.<init>(Default.java:14)
at main.JFD3.CreateGui(JFD3.java:260)
at main.JFD3.<init>(JFD3.java:252)
at main.Default.<init>(Default.java:14)
at main.JFD3.CreateGui(JFD3.java:260)
at main.JFD3.<init>(JFD3.java:252)
at main.Default.<init>(Default.java:14)
at main.JFD3.CreateGui(JFD3.java:260)
at main.JFD3.<init>(JFD3.java:252)
at main.Default.<init>(Default.java:14)
at main.JFD3.CreateGui(JFD3.java:260)
at main.JFD3.<init>(JFD3.java:252)
at main.Default.<init>(Default.java:14)
at main.JFD3.CreateGui(JFD3.java:260)
at main.JFD3.<init>(JFD3.java:252)
at main.Default.<init>(Default.java:14)
at main.JFD3.CreateGui(JFD3.java:260)
at main.JFD3.<init>(JFD3.java:252)
at main.Default.<init>(Default.java:14)
at main.JFD3.CreateGui(JFD3.java:260)
at main.JFD3.<init>(JFD3.java:252)
at main.Default.<init>(Default.java:14)
at main.JFD3.CreateGui(JFD3.java:260)
at main.JFD3.<init>(JFD3.java:252)
at main.Default.<init>(Default.java:14)
at main.JFD3.CreateGui(JFD3.java:260)
at main.JFD3.<init>(JFD3.java:252)
at main.Default.<init>(Default.java:14)
at main.JFD3.CreateGui(JFD3.java:260)
at main.JFD3.<init>(JFD3.java:252)
at main.Default.<init>(Default.java:14)
at main.JFD3.CreateGui(JFD3.java:260)
at main.JFD3.<init>(JFD3.java:252)
at main.Default.<init>(Default.java:14)
at main.JFD3.CreateGui(JFD3.java:260)
at main.JFD3.<init>(JFD3.java:252)
at main.Default.<init>(Default.java:14)
at main.JFD3.CreateGui(JFD3.java:260)
at main.JFD3.<init>(JFD3.java:252)
at main.Default.<init>(Default.java:14)
at main.JFD3.CreateGui(JFD3.java:260)
at main.JFD3.<init>(JFD3.java:252)
at main.Default.<init>(Default.java:14)
at main.JFD3.CreateGui(JFD3.java:260)
at main.JFD3.<init>(JFD3.java:252)
at main.Default.<init>(Default.java:14)
at main.JFD3.CreateGui(JFD3.java:260)
at main.JFD3.<init>(JFD3.java:252)
at main.Default.<init>(Default.java:14)
at main.JFD3.CreateGui(JFD3.java:260)
at main.JFD3.<init>(JFD3.java:252)
at main.Default.<init>(Default.java:14)
```

(actually only part of it bc its hella long)

Comment: Never  mind - I figured it out. I should not have called the CreateGui() method at the beginning of the JFD3.java, because it returned an error....just deleted it and it works just fine now.